# Redirecting stdout and stderr of specific lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

I am reading a file and redirecting the entire output to a file. I would like to redirect stdout and stderr of certain expressions to the screen as shown below (just an example):

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS
while IFS='|'
while read fname fpath dname dpath ; do
echo "$fname" >> redirect to screen
echo "$fpath"
echo "$dpath"
diff "$fpath/$fname" "$dpath/$dname" >> redirect to screen
done > logfile
```

I tried `>$(tty)` but that didn't work.
This didn't work either:

```
while read fname fpath dname dpath; do
echo "$fname" >&1
echo "$fpath"
echo "$dname"
echo "$dpath"
diff "$fpath/$fname" "$dpath/$dname" >&1
done > logfile
```

I can't use `tee` because it redirects the *entire* output to screen.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could do that using `awk`.

Comment: The question is why `tty` doesn't work. What does a call to `tty` in terminal print out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` loop is non-interactive, thus doesn't have a tty. You have to save your tty device before entering the loop. So you'd have something like:

```
my_tty=$(tty)

while read fname fpath dname dpath ; do
  echo "$fname" | tee ${my_tty}
  echo "$fpath"
  echo "$dpath"
  diff "$fpath/$fname" "$dpath/$dname" | tee ${my_tty}
done > logfile
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> while …; do
>   echo "$fname" >&1
> done > logfile
> ```

The standard output of the `echo` command is redirected to its standard output. In other words, `>&1` is a no-op. The `1` in `>&1` designates file descriptor 1 of the command where it is used, not of some mysteriously-chosen outer scope.

To redirect to a file that is available at an outer scope, duplicate the file descriptor in that outer scope, and don't redirect the duplicated file descriptor.

```
while read fname fpath dname dpath; do
  echo "$fname" >&3
  echo "$fpath"
  echo "$dname"
  echo "$dpath"
  diff "$fpath/$fname" "$dpath/$dname" >&3
done 3>&1 >logfile
```

Note the order of the redirections on the loop: first create a file descriptor 3 that goes where file descriptor 1 (standard output) is currently going, then redirect file descriptor 1 somewhere else.

Alternatively, you could open the log file on a different descriptor.

```
while read fname fpath dname dpath; do
  echo "$fname"
  echo "$fpath" >&3
  echo "$dname" >&3
  echo "$dpath" >&3
  diff "$fpath/$fname" "$dpath/$dname"
done 3>logfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. This really helped me since I am new to scripting. But, what should I do if I want to redirect a particular expression only to screen and not to file?

Comment: @Menon That's my first example: save the screen in a file descriptor (3 in my example) and use that for a particular instruction. Keep in mind that your script's output can itself be redirected, so this won't always be the terminal (there might not be a terminal at all, e.g. in a daemon or scheduled task).

Comment: So this wont work if I schedule my script in crontab?

Comment: @Menon If you redirect to the screen, this won't work in a crontab. But none of the examples I give redirect to the screen, and my point is that in general you shouldn't redirect to the screen.